# How do i tweak my YAML file so that it builds but does not deploy? I want to set up a PR Build pipeline to test build each PR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure

See below for my YAML code that I have in Azure pipeline, it is based off of a pipeline I created that works great for building and deploying.

I'm hoping to create a new pipeline that triggers when there is a PR to the "main" branch, and it builds the branch in the PR to see if there are any build issues before we merge it with the "main" branch. I believe the name for this is [Build Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation), but I'm stuck with creating the pipeline. Or is this right and I need to handle this with settings in the build validation setup?

I tried to update the YAML so it only runs when a PR is created, I think that part is okay. But I can't seem to figure out how to cancel the deployment part. The changes I make keep breaking in the build process of my existing normal pipeline.

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
trigger: none

jobs:
- job: build_and_deploy_job
  displayName: Build and Deploy Job
  condition: or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')))
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  variables:
  - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps
  steps:  
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS)
###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
# For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
      app_location: "/" # App source code path
      api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
      output_location: "" # Built app content directory - optional
    env:
        NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_KEY: $(NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_KEY)

###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
```

Comment: To tweak your YAML file so that it builds but does not deploy, you can remove the AzureStaticWebApp@0 task from your build_and_deploy_job job. This task is responsible for deploying the built app content to Azure Static Web Apps. By removing this task, your pipeline will only build the app and not deploy it.

To set up a PR Build pipeline to test build each PR, you can modify your YAML file to include a pullRequest trigger and remove the trigger: none line. This will trigger the pipeline to run whenever a pull request is created or updated on the main branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To tweak your YAML file so that it builds but does not deploy, you can remove the  `AzureStaticWebApp@0`  task from your  `build_and_deploy_job`  job. This task is responsible for deploying the built app content to Azure Static Web Apps. By removing this task, your pipeline will only build the app and not deploy it.

To set up a PR Build pipeline to test build each PR, you can modify your YAML file to include a  `pullRequest`  trigger and remove the  `trigger: none`  line. This will trigger the pipeline to run whenever a pull request is created or updated on the  `main`  branch. You can also remove the  `condition`  line to simplify the pipeline.

Here's an example YAML file that builds but does not deploy, and triggers on pull requests to the  `main`  branch:

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: build_job
  displayName: Build Job
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  variables:
  - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps
  steps:  
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - run: |
      # Add your Build details here
```

AzureStaticWebApp@0 task is specifically designed for deploying to Azure Static Web Apps, including both the build and deploy process as part of its operation. By removing this task, you prevent the pipeline from deploying your application, aligning with your goal to only build the app during PR validation.

By specifying a `pr` trigger with the `main` branch included, you ensure that the pipeline is automatically triggered whenever a pull request targeting the `main` branch is created or updated.

Removing `trigger: none` is necessary to activate the `pr` triggers. With `trigger: none`, you would disable all automatic triggers for your pipeline, which contradicts the goal of having the pipeline run on pull requests. By removing it, you allow the pull request triggers to function.

Simplifying the pipeline by removing the conditional execution. The original condition was designed to control the execution of the build and deploy job based on the reason for the build (e.g., Manual, PullRequest, IndividualCI). For a pipeline focused solely on PR build validation, removing this condition simplifies the configuration without sacrificing functionality. The pipeline will now run unconditionally for pull requests to the `main` branch, which is the intended behavior.

References:

- [Build multiple branches in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/ci-build-git?view=azure-devops#customize-build-tasks-based-on-the-branch-being-built)

Comment: thank you!  Great breakdown of what each step/job is doing. Going to edit and try now

Comment: alright so i think i got it to work with your edits, marking as sovled. thank you!    I cant give your answer an up vote cause my account is too new though...